# Doctrine; if - else null

Tags: php, sql, symfony, doctrine-orm

Thanks for reading,

I'm facing an issue which I just can't seem to fix myself. I was hoping that people could point me in the right direction.

I'm querying some results for my datagrid :

```
    $datagrid = new Datagrid();

    $datasource = new DoctrineSource(
        $entityManager->getRepository('PricelistBundle:PricelistMaterial')
    );

    $datasource->getQueryBuilder()->addSelect('pg');
    $datasource->getQueryBuilder()->leftJoin('t.pricelistmaterialprice', 'pg');
    $datasource->getQueryBuilder()->leftJoin('t.material', 'g');
    $datasource->getQueryBuilder()->andWhere('pg.year <= :year');
    $datasource->getQueryBuilder()->andWhere('pg.week <= :week');
    $datasource->getQueryBuilder()->andWhere('t.pricelist = :pricelist');
    $datasource->getQueryBuilder()->setParameters(['year' => $year, 'week' => $week, 'pricelist' => $pricelist]);

    $datagrid->setDatasource($datasource);
```

Now I'm getting the results where week = week and year = year. But the point is, when the chosen week is for example bigger then the weeks known, my result is null.

**What I would like is that the results would still been shown, but then with just prices as 0.
That would mean something like: Where pg.year <= :year, else pg is null, in that way I could keep the results of my other tables.**

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work as you'd expect a left join to:

```
$datasource->getQueryBuilder()->leftJoin('t.pricelistmaterialprice', 'pg', 'WITH', 'pg.year <= :year AND pg.week <= :week');
```

See [docs on leftJoin](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/query-builder.html#high-level-api-methods)

Comment: Thanks, haven't thought about approaching it this way. Thanks!